# Error: Expected float64, got 'collections' of type 'str' instead

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I'm training a text classification model. The text is a word vector processed by word2vec, but I have a problem. Below is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/github文件/my-project/main.py", line 65, in <module>
    history = txt_net.fit(text_train, train_onehot_label, batch_size=32, epochs=3,
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 66, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 848, in fit
    tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 580, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 627, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 505, in _initialize
    self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2446, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2777, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2657, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 981, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 441, in wrapped_fn
    return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 968, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)

TypeError: in user code:

    E:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:571 train_function  *
        outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
    E:\github文件\my-project\train_model.py:65 call  *
        x = self.inpu(x)
    E:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py:1491 tensor_equals  **
        return gen_math_ops.equal(self, other, incompatible_shape_error=False)
    E:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py:3222 equal
        _, _, _op, _outputs = _op_def_library._apply_op_helper(
    E:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py:475 _apply_op_helper
        raise TypeError(

    TypeError: Expected float64 passed to parameter 'y' of op 'Equal', got 'collections' of type 'str' instead. Error: Expected float64, got 'collections' of type 'str' instead.
```

进程已结束,退出代码1
This is the text model I use,

```
class TextNet(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, vocab_dim, n_symbols, embedding_weights, input_length):
        super(TextNet, self).__init__()
        self.inpu = Input(shape=100, name="text_input")
        self.embedding = Embedding(output_dim=vocab_dim, input_dim=n_symbols, mask_zero=True,
                                   weights=[embedding_weights],
                                   input_length=input_length, trainable=False)
        self.lstm = LSTM(64, activation='relu')
        self.dropout1 = Dropout(0.2)
        self.dense = Dense(512, activation='relu')
        self.dropout2 = Dropout(0.2)
        self.dense1 = Dense(38, activation='softmax')

    def call(self, x, **kwargs):
        x = self.inpu(x)
        x = self.embedding(x)
        x = self.lstm(x)
        x = self.dropout1(x)
        x = self.dense(x)
        x = self.dropout2(x)
        x = self.dense1(x)
        return x
    txt_net = TextNet(vocab_dim, n_symbols, embedding_weights, input_length)
    txt_net.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    history = txt_net.fit(text_train, train_onehot_label, batch_size=32, epochs=3,
                              validation_split=0.3,
                              verbose=1)
```

Comment: Has been resolved
x = self.inpu(x),You don't need this

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss= tf.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
metrics= ['accuracy'])
```

Comment: I tried this. It didn't work. But thank you for sharing. The error has been solved by me.